# How to rotate thumbnail image in ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using this code for my thumbnail image

```
<?php 
$ffmpeg = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'; 
$second = 2;
$video = 'video/123.mp4';    
$image = 'thumb/123.jpg';
$command = "$ffmpeg  -itsoffset -$second  -i $video -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 175x150 $image";
```

its giving me the thumbnail image BUT i want to rotate that thumbnail image. I already tried **transpose** and **rotate** but nothing happen even i lost the thumbnail image also.

**Tried solutions but nothing happen :-**

```
$command ="$ffmpeg -itsoffset -$second -i $video -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -vf 'transpose=1' -an -f rawvideo -s 175x150 $image";
```

and

```
$command ="$ffmpeg -itsoffset -$second -i $video -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -vf 'rotate=PI/2' -an -f rawvideo -s 175x150 $image";
```

Please help me.....

Comment: You could try rotating the image with PHP...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259881/how-to-rotate-image-and-save-the-image

Comment: @user3675480: its good but do you know how to do this with the ffmpeg command.

Comment: You need to include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937387/rotating-videos-with-ffmpeg